# How to superimpose two ggplots of numeric objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to plot two ggplots superimposed one on another. I have seen there are many questions have been asked on this in this forum. But I am not getting desired result just by simply following them (definitely I am doing something wrong). Here is the codes for two plots:

```
cdf1 <- ggplot ( melt(X0)$values) , aes( x = value )) + stat_ecdf(geom="density" )

cdf2 <- ggplot ( melt(Y0)$values) , aes( x = value )) + stat_ecdf(geom="step" )
```

X0 and Y0 are two 80X80 matrices. 
Now when I am trying to superimpose these two plots with the following code, it is throwing some error.

```
cdf <- ggplot ( (eigen(X0)$values) , aes( x = value )) + 
  stat_ecdf (geom="density" ) + 
  geom_step( melt(eigen(Y0)$values) , aes( x = value ))
```

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Would anyone please tell me how to achieve this superposition?

Comment: Here's a blind guess as we don't have access to your actual datasets... try replacing `melt(eigen(Y0)$values)` with `data = melt(eigen(Y0)$values)` in `geom_step()`?

Comment: Dear Lin, Thanks for the advice. That actually works. I tried the following as you told.

    `cdf <- ggplot ( melt(eigen(Rcov)$values) , aes( x = value )) + stat_ecdf (geom="density" ) + geom_step( data = melt(eigen(Hycov)$values) , aes( x = value ))` 

But then when I am asking for the plot it shows error.

`> cdf
Error: geom_step requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

Comment: Try `stat_ecdf(data = melt(eigen(Hycov)$values) , aes( x = value ), geom = "step")` instead?